# Need help with second order taylor expansion - Where is $\frac{1}{2}$ term?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:

$$(, , ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}}$$

Gradient is:

$$ \frac{-(x,y,z)^T}{\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}^3}$$

At point $$P = (1,1,-1)$$

Gradient is: $$ -\frac{1}{3\sqrt 3} \cdot (1,1,-1)^T$$

Hessian matrix is:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\1&0&-1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}

Scalar of Hessian Matrix is:
$$\frac{1}{3\sqrt 3}$$

Solution gives second order taylor approximation as:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt3} - \frac{1}{3\sqrt3}\cdot(x-1+y-1-z-1) + \frac{1}{3\sqrt3}((x-1)(y-1)-(x-1)(z+1)-(y-1)(z+1))$$

According to my lecture notes the second order Taylor approximation is given as (2d case, a,b = point of expansion, D = gradient, H  = Hessian matrix)

\begin{align*}
  t_{app}(x,y) &= f(a,b) + D f(a,b)
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      x-a \\ y-b
    \end{array}
  \right]
  \\
  &\quad
  + \frac{1}{2}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      x-a &y-b
    \end{array}
  \right]
  Hf(a,b) 
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      x-a \\ y-b
    \end{array}
  \right]
\end{align*}

I'm completely lost here, where is the following part in the solution? $$\frac{1}{2}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      x-a &y-b
    \end{array}
  \right] $$

EDIT: I found out that the $\frac{1}{2}$ term applies only to the elements in the diagonal. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want to understand why you have $\frac12$ in the Taylor expansion? Or do you want to see what is the corresponding term in the solution?

Comment: The second, I can't find the $\frac{1}{2}$ part in the solution. But studying another solution they dismiss the  $\frac{1}{2}$ part for all elements not in diagonal. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3D case, the term is the Taylor expansion you are looking for is $$\frac12 \begin{bmatrix}x-a&y-b&z-c\end{bmatrix}Hf(a,b,c)\begin{bmatrix}x-a\\y-b\\z-c\end{bmatrix}$$
In your case $a=b=1$, $c=-1$, and $$Hf(a,b,c)=\frac1{3\sqrt3}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\1&0&-1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore:$$\frac12 \begin{bmatrix}x-1&y-1&z+1\end{bmatrix}\frac1{3\sqrt3}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\1&0&-1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x-1\\y-1\\z+1\end{bmatrix}=\\ \frac1{3\sqrt3}\frac12\begin{bmatrix}x-1&y-1&z+1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}(y-1)-(z+1)\\(x-1)-(z+1)\\-(x-1)-(y-1)\end{bmatrix}=\\\frac1{3\sqrt3}\frac12\left((x-1)(y-1)-(x-1)(z+1)+(y-1)(x-1)\\-(y-1)(z+1)-(z+1)(x-1)-(z+1)(y-1)\right)$$
Notice that each product appears twice, so that's a factor of $2$ that cancels the $\frac12$ in front, so the Hessian term of the Taylor expansion becomes
$$\frac1{3\sqrt3}\left((x-1)(y-1)-(x-1)(z+1)-(y-1)(z+1)\right)$$

Comment: Finally..Thanks very much for clearing the confusion...